# Discrete Harmonic Oscillator matrix representation of $x$ for Quantum Simulation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, computational-physics

(The paper I'm referring to in this question is "[Quantum simulations of one dimensional quantum systems](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.06319)")

I've been trying to understand the paper above, specifically on constructing a matrix representation of the position operator, $\hat{x}$, in discrete real space (Equation (11)).

> In analogy with the CV QHO, we define a discrete
> QHO by the Hamiltonian
> $$H^{\text{d}}=\frac{1}{2}((x^{\text{d}})^2+(p^{\text{d}})^2). \tag{10}$$
> The Hilbert space dimension is $N$, where $N\geq 2$ is even
> for simplicity. $x^{\text{d}}$ is the discrete "position" operator
> given by the $N\times N$ diagonal matrix
> $$x^{\text{d}} = \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{N}}\frac{1}{2}
> \begin{pmatrix}
> -N & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
> 0 & -(N+2) & \dots & 0 \\
> \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
> 0 & 0 & \dots & (N-2)
> \end{pmatrix}, \tag{11}$$

I'm quite a bit lost on how this matrix is derived. Since we are in the basis of real space, I expect that the matrix should be diagonal (as it is). My guess is that the basis of real space that we are in is really the basis of Hermite Polynomials: the diagonal entries are the entries that would satisfy something along the lines of:

$$ \hat{H} H_n(x) = a_{nn}H_n(x)$$

where $a_{nn}$ is the diagonal entry in the $n$th row and column, and $H_n(x)$ is the $n$th Hermite polynomial.

I'm not entirely sure if this is proper thinking, so any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is it: It seems like we can treat $X$ as the Fourier transform of $p$ to explain the factors.

Comment: I think (11) is a definition (not derived). (15) appears to express approximate eigenvalues of $H^d$ as sums of eigenvalues of $x^d$ (the $\vert j \rangle$), with Hermite function coefficients.